# Uninstalling Mathematica

Tags: installation

If I want to uninstall Mathematica and completely remove it from my computer, should I first uninstall extra packages and then the software itself or just uninstall Mathematica?

P.S. Operating system: Windows.

Comment: Some relevant links: [this](https://support.wolfram.com/12473) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141538/how-to-uninstall-mathematica-in-linux).

Comment: Not sure, but I think "symbolic links" is mostly a Unix/Linux thing. You should in any case say in your question what your operating system is, maybe also which packages you want to uninstall, and which part of your question is not covered by existing resources (like the ones I linked to).

Comment: What do you mean by "extra packages"? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica settings and packages are usually present in subdirectories of [`$UserBaseDirectory`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html).  You do not need to remove these before uninstalling Mathematica.  If you choose to keep these, the settings and packages will be there when you reinstall Mathematica (or install a different version) later.

If you want to remove these, you can do so without having Mathematica installing. Just delete that directory. Be sure to take a note of where this directory is before uninstalling Mathematica.

Comment: @Marteen Only relevant on Linux. The installer will create symlinks to Mathematica's executables in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` (don't remember which).